# woocommerce API v3 filter by meta data

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I want to link all woo-commerce data in my ERP system

so I started with a customer by using woo-commerce APIs v3

I send a request to store the customer in woo-commerce and add a meta_data key called [code ] which is used to link customers in woo-commerce with customers in my ERP system.

now I want to update the customer by code in meta_data, but in woo-commerce APIs documentation, there is no search or filter by meta_data !!? how can I filter by meta_data in woo commerce also can't save id manually for the customer cause it's auto-generated

is there any way so that I can find a customer by meta_data value

Comment: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query#adding-custom-parameter-support this might help you